# Writing a custom QPushButton class in Python

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

I've recently started learning PyQt on my own and I've come in some trouble trying to write a custom class that inherits from QPushButton so I can adjust its attributes. I'm trying to pass a text as an argument whenever I initialize an object of this class. I am pretty sure there's something wrong with my **init** but I haven't found it yet. 
Here is the code:

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore


class mainb(QtGui.QPushButton):
    def __init__(Text,self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupbt(Text)

    def setupbt(self):
        self.setFlat(True)
        self.setText(Text)
        self.setGeometry(200,100, 60, 35)
        self.move(300,300)
        print('chegu aqui')
        self.setToolTip('Isso é muito maneiro <b>Artur</b>')
        self.show()


class mainwindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self , parent = None):
        super().__init__()        
        self.setupgui()
    def setupgui(self):
        self.setToolTip('Oi <i>QWidget</i> widget')       
        self.resize(800,600)
        self.setWindowTitle('Janela do Artur')
        af = mainb("Bom dia",self)
        self.show()
"""
        btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Botão',self)
        btn.clicked.connect(QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit)
        btn.resize(btn.sizeHint())
        btn.move(300, 50)
"""



def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = mainwindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using super in wrong way, super must get a instance and another thing your first arg is Text, that's wrong that should be self. I fixed some more and the below code should work for you

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore


class mainb(QtGui.QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, Text, parent = None):
        super(mainb, self).__init__()
        self.setupbt(Text)

    def setupbt(self, Text):
        self.setFlat(True)
        self.setText(Text)
        self.setGeometry(200,100, 60, 35)
        self.move(300,300)
        print('chegu aqui')
        self.setToolTip('Isso muito maneiro <b>Artur</b>')
        self.show()


class mainwindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self , parent = None):
        super(mainwindow, self).__init__()    
        self.setupgui()
    def setupgui(self):
        self.setToolTip('Oi <i>QWidget</i> widget')       
        self.resize(800,600)
        self.setWindowTitle('Janela do Artur')
        newLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        af = mainb("Bom dia",self)
        newLayout.addWidget(af)
        self.setLayout(newLayout)
        self.show()


def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = mainwindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Since *QPushButton* accept a text argument, it is also possible to write: `super(mainb, self).__init__(Text, parent)`. Then no need to pass `Text` as an argument of `setupbt` method and no need to call `self.setText(Text)`.

Comment: If he's using Python 3, the call to super().__init__(parent) is perfectly valid.

Comment: I didn't saw that in his question, which version he was using. anyways looks like he abandon this thread ;)

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm using Python 3.4

Comment: Achayan's way worked just fine. I've tried passing:         super(mainb, self).__init__(Text, parent = None)
but it did not work

Answer (score 0):

Your `def setupbt(self)` does not seem to take the text as argument. Try `def setupbt(self, Text):` instead.

Comment: I get this error when I do that: 
 File "C:\Artur\Programação\t1.py", line 28, in setupgui
    af = mainb("Bom dia",self)
  File "C:\Artur\Programação\t1.py", line 8, in __init__
    self.setupbt(Text)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'setupbt'